# What does windows 10 do if the disk is filled at 99.99%?

Tags: windows-10

I have a server that was left alone for a long time and because of an application automatic backup (not sure with what privileges) it had reached 95% capacity (7GB free out of 142GB). It used to have two SQL Server installations in it and I can find only one now.

What would Windows 10 do if something forces it to write beyond 99% capacity ? Any chance it could uninstall programs on its own ?

Comment: It will probably throw notifications indicating the free space on the disk was extremely low. Services using that disk space would continue until they themselves crash.

Comment: Furthermore Stoage Sense configurations can change the default behavior some here proactively in terms of low Windows disk storage and automatic disk cleanup operations as you can configure accordingly but see  [Manage drive space with Storage Sense](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-drive-space-with-storage-sense-654f6ada-7bfc-45e5-966b-e24aded96ad5)

Comment: Start with a Windows bootable USB and delete items you know can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too vague and general, but
according to my own experience, if Windows doesn't have enough disk space for
its own maintenance, then it can get into serious trouble.

I twice had the experience of Windows dying out when the system disk filled
up, to the point that it couldn't be salvaged and had to be re-installed
from scratch. This happened some time ago, and free space was then 0% and not
5%, but I took away the impression that insufficient disk space
can cause anything to happen.

That said, a whole SQL installation is still unlikely to vanish totally
into thin air. There should still be some trace left of it, such as folders
and files. If everything was cleaned out, this means human interaction,
and not just a Windows glitch.

Comment: I supposed free space might have gotten much closer to 0% before something happened to the SQL, and then it became the 5% free space i saw. But it seems indeed unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

When there's not enough disk space, operations to write, save, copy, install, etc. will get interrupted. For example:

[image: Not enough space]

Windows 10 will **not** uninstall software due to disk space.

Some example situations that could be disk-space related are:

- if you didn't have enough space, the second database instance might crash or fail to start
- if you have a process to clear and reload a database, the clear would work, but loading would fail